# Comparing values from rows with the same group id?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm trying to write a SQL query to do the following:

Given the following table:

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | group_id | value     |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 1  | 1        | 0         |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 2  | 1        | 0         |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 3  | 2        | null      |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 4  | 3        | -1        |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 5  | 3        | 1         |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 6  | 4        | something |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 7  | 5        | something |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

select * 
where values do not equal each other
group by group_id

For this example, output should be:

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | group_id | value     |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 4  | 1        | -1        |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 5  | 1        | 1         |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Also mention the output so we can get more information

Comment: you wrote wrong query where is value1 and value2

Comment: Your question is totally unclear.  `value1` and `value2` are not in the data you have shown.  Please explain the logic.  And show the results that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to find the `group_id` values which have different `value`, you can use this query:

```
SELECT group_id
FROM data
GROUP BY group_id
HAVING MIN(value) != MAX(value)
```

Output for your sample data:

```
group_id
3
```

If you want to get the rows that are associated with that `group_id`, use the above query as a subquery for an `IN` expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE group_id IN (
  SELECT group_id
  FROM data
  GROUP BY group_id
  HAVING MIN(value) != MAX(value)
)
```

Output

```
id  group_id    value
4   3           -1
5   3           1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nWLTsdcsBFGdhbRnDftvH3/0)

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `exists` to get group_id which does not have same value. here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9p3J8LvpWr69ndeUgwtdQ1/1).

```
select
    distinct group_id
from data d1
where exists
(
    select
        group_id
    from data d2
    where d1.group_id = d2.group_id
    and d1.value <> d2.value
)
```

Output

```
*--------*
|group_id|
*--------*
|     3  |
*--------*
```

If you want group_id and value both then try the follwoing

```
select
    group_id,
    value
from data d1
where exists
(
    select
        group_id
    from data d2
    where d1.group_id = d2.group_id
    and d1.value <> d2.value
)
```

Output:

```
*------------------*
|group_id |  value |
*------------------*
|     3  |    -1   |
|     3  |     1   |
*------------------*
```

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
select group_id
from tablename
group by group_id
having count(distinct value) > 1 and count(distinct value) = count(value)
```

returns the `group_id`s that you want, so use it with the operator `IN`:

```
select * from tablename
where group_id in (
  select group_id
  from tablename
  group by group_id
  having count(distinct value) > 1 and count(distinct value) = count(value)
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vcKPa8VEi7x3NfBLHJPuLL/0).
Results:

```
| id  | group_id | value |
| --- | -------- | ----- |
| 4   | 3        | -1    |
| 5   | 3        | 1     |
```